# Serial data stops when notepad window is opened

Tags: python, serial-port, subprocess

I am writing a script in python where in I have a arduino sending me data. I have to open notepad from the script and write the data collected through serial COM in the notepad.

For opening notepad I am using subprocess module

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.Popen(('notepad.exe').split(),shell=True).communicate()
```

the serial data is stalled until I close the notepad window after which all the serial data is displayed. Is there a way I can get the serial data after notepad window is opened..?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: unrelated: you could write the data to a file using python instead of opening notepad and write the data by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Popen` without any `communicate()`; you are not piping the standard streams anywhere anyhow.

So:

```
sp.Popen(['notepad.exe'])
```

You can store the process object to a variable, and call `.poll()` on it to see if it has completed; it will return `None` until it has completed:

```
proc = sp.Popen(['notepad.exe'])
...
if proc.poll() is not None:
    print("Notepad completed")
else:
    print("Notepad is still running")
```